# How to have myname.github.io as url of a personal website on GitHub?

Tags: url, github, github-pages

I want to set up a personal website on Github. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwThn0rxv7M) to create a repository containing a file `index.html`.

I read online that in order to obtain an url `<myname>.github.io` for this html page, you need to name the respository `<myname>.github.io`. But when I do this, the html page gets published to `<accountname>.github.io/<myname>.github.io`. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://pages.github.com:

> Head over to GitHub and create a new repository named
>   *username*.github.io, where *username* is your username (or organization
>   name) on GitHub.
>
> If the first part of the repository doesn’t exactly match your
>   username, it won’t work, so make sure to get it right.

Comment: OK, I did not get that the name of your page has to be the same as your Github account name.